# RC snubber circuit on reversing motor

Tags: dc-motor, snubber

I have an RC snubber that is in parallel to a DC motor that runs forward and reverse.

Is this snubber going to work differently in the forward direction than it does in the reverse direction? Does the resistor/capacitor orientation matter with respect to applied voltage?

[image: RC Snubber]

Comment: No, your circuit is bipolar in this regard. Flipping the R and C makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

An RC snubber is perfectly linear, you only have resistors and non-polarized (usually film or ceramic) capacitors. So it work exactly in the same way both in the forward and in the reverse direction.

The *other* common encountered snubber (the RCD) is not, since it has a diode: like this, it's used for dampening inductive switches but it's optimized since the spike is only in one direction. That won't work in a bidirectional brushed motor.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the capacitors are not polarized (and generally capacitors << 1 μF are not polarized), electrically the arrangement of R & C in series doesn't matter. Therefore the snubber will work identically in either polarity of motor drive.

Comment: Tantalum caps are polarized. I don't see them too often nowadays, but just thought I would mention it. Why did you choose to answer this old question?